# D3 Paths from external data not appearing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, geojson

I have downloaded a file from OSM and taken a few coordinates to practice loading data from a GeoJSON and writing them into an SVG. Most of the JS code is taken from the maps tutorial by D3Vienno but even though I do not get errors I cannot get anything to appear on screen. Here is the JS file:

```
window.onload = function(){

var canvas = d3.selectAll("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 600)
    .attr("height", 600)

d3.json("test.geojson", function (data){

    var group = canvas.selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")

    var projection= d3.geo.albers();

    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection); //.scale(450).translate([0, 1980]);

    var areas = group.append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("class", "area")
        .style("stroke-width", 1)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "steelblue");


});
}
```

The GeoJSON file has been validated by jsonformatter and I also built a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7joagLar/1/) of it to see if that makes a difference.

If I don't comment out the `.scale(450).translate([0, 1980])` portion I get a "is not a function error" but it is in the API and I believe it is formatted correctly.

Here is also the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/d3.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="test.geojson"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mapPractice.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

If I don't comment out the script tag for the GeoJSON I get "unexpected token error : in the GeoJSON file and this continues to happen until I delete everything but the coordinates, and then I get "Cannot read property 'length' of null" in the D3 file. Sorry for such a multi-part question but I've been trying to understand this problem for days and I just go in circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both, `.scale()` and `.translate()` are methods of the [`d3.geo.projection`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#projection), not of [`d3.geo.path()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#path). You probably want something like this:

```
var projection= d3.geo.albers()
  .scale(450).translate([0, 1980]);   // Call .scale() and .translate() on the projection!

var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
```

Furthermore, in your JSFiddle you are binding your data like this:

```
var group = canvas.selectAll("g")
  .data(data.coordinates)
```

Because this will only bind the array of coordinates there is no input to the geo path generator which expects GeoJSON. For the `LineString` to be rendered you need to bind as this:

```
var group = canvas.selectAll("g")
  .data([data])
```

Examining the SVG's source code you can see, that this does actually insert the path although it will not get rendered because it is to small and off screen. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/7joagLar/6/) should give you a good starting point from where to optimize scale and translation to render it the way you need it to.

Answer (score 1):

d3.json() can be slightly tricky to understand.  Buried in [the explanation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json), you'll see:

> the callback is invoked with two arguments: the error, if any, and the parsed JSON

So, you might try

```
d3.json("test.geojson", function (error, data) {
```

The first argument to the callback is the error (which will be null or undefined if your json file gets read correctly).